# Best strategy to share some sensitive user data between Node and PHP

Tags: php, session-management, node.js

I am creating a website that is built on PHP. It has a small page where users can have a group chat and message each other. For that page I open a websocket with a help of `socket.io` and `expressjs`. I want to use usernames that people registered with. And, of course, I want people not be able to impersonate other people. So, once user enters a message, it gets `socket.emit`ed to the server, and from the server I do something like:

```
socket.on('message', function(msg) {
    io.emit('message', {
        username: username
        message: msg
    });
});
```

To broadcast that message to everyone.

My question is, how do I retrieve the username? My solution at the moment is this. I create a unique 128 chars long user_id on user sign up, store in redis something like

`user_id: username`,

and then I pass `user_id` on `socket.emit` and do on Node server

`username: redisClient.get("user_id")`.

Is it a good idea? Is it secure? Or there are better solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

From my perspective your case fits very well with JSON Web Token (JWT) approach. You can encode all necessary data in JWT and pass it with requests. Your Node.js application should verify signature of JWT and extract all needed data from it. If something is too big / complex to put in JWT, than backend application may request for this data another backend service for it via your backend network security mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but from my understanding of JWT, wouldn't people be able to decode the string I pass from PHP service, add any username (or other data) to it, encode it, and pass it to my Nodejs server? Then they could impersonate any user.

Comment: Oh, although I can see we can provide secret key it seems, then it would be a perfect solution!

Comment: To protect against that JWT is being signed by entity which creates it. In your case PHP application will issue JWT, sign it and sent to client. Client then will send it to Node.js application. Node.js will first check signature. Check will not pass if client alters JWT.

Comment: I am able to decode the jwt token with http://jwt.calebb.net/, even though I add a key generating the jwt token. Any ideas why? I thought you need a secret key to decode the data.

Comment: It can always decoded, but successful verification can be done only when secret key is known in Node server, right?